# WCF wrapper COM object

Tags: wcf, com

I have a third party COM component (they don't offer a .Net assy), that has the additional feature that it only works under x86 compile.

I am trying to wrap this in a WCF service, but if I select x86, the service won't start (System.BadImageFormatException).

Any workarounds for this ?

Thanks
Larry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the VS2008 WCF debugger will only start up in 64bit. I solved the problem by creating a 32bit host and running that